# How do I adjust my 2D game to every resolution?

Tags: .net, 2d, resolution, scaling

I'm coding a 2D game in C# using Windows Forms and the `System.Drawing` namespace.

The game is basically a battle arena (an orange square) where players shoot at each other. This is how the arena looks like (800x600 resolution): https://i.gyazo.com/54f56cead5c42519678e48118d20947b.png

Since my game is not open world, the requirement is that every player will always see 100% of the battle arena, no matter their resolution.

I have a problem scaling everything to fit the arena with different resolutions.

For example, the game resolution is 800x600, so the arena is roughly 780x580 pixels. The user suddenly resizes the window to 1280x720, so the arena immediately changes to be roughly 1260x700 pixels. It is problematic for one major reason:

The game is designed to be a multiplayer game, where every player can play in a different resolution. There are 2 things that have to be scaled: The position of objects (X,Y) and their size (Width,Height).

I've seen other questions about scaling, but they deal with open-world games, where a lower resolution just means seeing less of the map. In my case, it is a requirement that all the players always see 100% of the game's contents.

I've tried to scale both, but it ends up looking too big or too small due to the scaling of the position being unsuitable for the scaling of the size, or vice versa.

How can I scale everything effectively (so everyone sees 100% of the game's content all the time), especially when multiple users with different resolutions play the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine the horizontal and the vertical scaling factor and scale both by the smallest factor. This way the entire field will fit. Scale the positions and sizes of the sprites to this factor as well.

Wrap the scaling code in a separate control that hides the factor so the rest of the game can assume a fixed size.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I've done. I have a method that divides the actual width by the initial game width, and the actual height by the initial game height, and then returns the smallest ratio.

The problem is that sometimes, if the user keeps resizing the form to add more width but not to change the height (only to the left/right), the size of the objects stop changing at a certain point, but the arena keeps fitting itself to the sides (the arena is sides minus 50 pixels). In this user, the proportion between the arena size and the objects' size is lost.

Comment: Don't fit the arena to the full width. Add black side bars similar to letter boxing for tv

Comment: This is what it looks like when I scale it to the minimum ratio (the default resolution is 800x600, this is 1920x1040): https://i.gyazo.com/6131c10dcfca3567b74de508f06b148c.png

Is the arena supposed to have constant width and height properties, or should it be dynamic? If it should be dynamic, should I multiply it by the smaller scale of the ratio between width and height? Right now it looks weird that there is too much free space on the right side.

Comment: @BlueRay101 - that is up to you. Looking at the picture, you added a bar at the right hand size and that is a solution. Give the arena a fixed size in the application and only scale within the control. My guess is that the scaling factor is slightly off because the scaling factor is getting scaled. Always recalculate the factor from scratch to prevent rounding errors that accumulate.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, Erno! Will give the arena a fixed size to prevent certain problems between multiple players in a server, where every player has a different resolution.